# Data Binding returning null values

Tags: c#, excel, data-binding, epplus

So I'm trying to read an excel file and insert the data to class properties. I think theres a problem when I instanitae the class, however I'm doing it before I'm parsing and adding the values to the class.

Once the parsing has completed - I call the bound class but it returns nulls.

**The Calls**

```
        TestData td = new TestData();

        XLReader.GetClassFromExcel<TestData>(1,1,1);

        var ddddd = td.Title; //this is null.
```

**The Class**

```
    public class TestData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string OrderRef { get; set; }
    public string ReqBy { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }

}
```

**The Parsing of the Excel**

```
public static class XLReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The deployment files folder name
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly string deploymentFilesFolderName =
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    public static List<T> GetClassFromExcel<T>(int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toColumn = 0)
    {

        var path = Path.Combine(deploymentFilesFolderName, @"Tools\TestData.xlsx");
        List<T> retList = new List<T>();
        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            //Retrieve first Worksheet
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            //If the to column is empty or 0, then make the tocolumn to the count of the properties
            //Of the class object inserted
            toColumn = toColumn == 0 ? typeof(T).GetProperties().Count() : toColumn;

            //Read the first Row for the column names and place into a list so that
            //it can be used as reference to properties
            List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
            // wsRow = ws.Row(0);
            foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Cells.Count()])
            {
                columnNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
            }

            //Loop through the rows of the excel sheet
            for (var rowNum = fromRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                //create a instance of T
                T objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                //Retrieve the type of T
                Type myType = typeof(T);
                //Get all the properties associated with T
                PropertyInfo[] myProp = myType.GetProperties();

                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, fromColumn, rowNum, ws.Cells.Count()];

                foreach (var propertyInfo in myProp)
                {
                    if (columnNames.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
                    {
                        int position = columnNames.IndexOf(propertyInfo.Name);
                        //To prevent an exception cast the value to the type of the property.
                        var blah = Convert.ChangeType(wsRow[rowNum, position + 1].Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(objT,blah);

                    }
                }

                retList.Add(objT);
            }

        }
        return retList;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var td  = XLReader.GetClassFromExcel<TestData>(1,1,1)[0];`

Comment: Thanks @KooKiz, that works. Next step for me is how to I get the data in the class so whenever I call TestData().Site (in any other class) it will return the data?

Comment: Wouldnt you just do `td.Site` to get at the data?

Answer (score 0):

When I import excel data, I always create a string array to store the value with this code

```
package.Load(fileContent.InputStream);
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

int totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
int totalCols = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
List<myObject> listMyObject = new List<myObject>();
for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow <= totalRows; currentRow++)
{
    string[] resultRow = new string[totalCols];
    for (int currentCol = 1; currentCol <= totalCols; currentCol++)
    {
        //We read the entire line and store it in the array
        resultRow[currentCol - 1] = (workSheet.Cells[currentRow, currentCol].Value != null) ? workSheet.Cells[currentRow, currentCol].Value.ToString() : "";
    }

   //And now I can bind my array to my object
   listMyObject.Add(myObjectHelper.Convert(resultRow));
}
//Here i've got my list object
```

My array will contains at worst an empty string. In this case I know there was nothing filled in my Excel file.

And after I convert my string array to my object